# Display a pdf that is loaded via webview (android)

Tags: android, pdf, webview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm looking for a way to display a pdf that is loaded in a webview. 
The case is as follows:
- We load a (external) web application inside a webview. 
- The web application is secured, users have to login to access their data. 
- When the user has logged in there is a button for downloading a pdf file.
- On iOS the pdf file is being displayed inside the webview, on Android it isn't.
- It is not possible to access the pdf by using a webservice instead of the webview (so, Titanium.Network.HTTPClient cannot be used)

We tried several solutions that we found on the internet. Unfortunately, till now without any success.

We tried:
- Google's documentviewer: http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=. This is not working because the pdf is 'behind' a username/password. Google is not aware of the session.
- Saving the pdf to the local file system and open it with Android Intent. We did not succeed in saving the pdf on the local filesystem.

The last option (saving the pdf and open it by using Ti.Android.Intent) seems to be the best option. But is it possible to save a pdf from a webview???

Maybe an external module (or using pdf.js) is also an option.

Can someone point me in the right direction.
We even don't know if what we want is possible?

Any help is really appreciated.

Stefan.